# VBA to Save active workbook getting method error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save the active workbook using vba as an xlsb file...with its current name and add "_current date".

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\sxj2030\Documents\BC Validations\Fixed\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "_" & Format(Date, "MMMddYYYY"), FileFormat = xlExcel12
```

I am getting the "Method 'SaveAs'of object'_WorkBook' Failed" error an I'm at a loss as to why

Comment: I think you miss a colon `FileFormat := xlExcel12`

Comment: And the File Extension too :)

Comment: @Sam: I think you should put it as an answer :)

Comment: I hate my life every Monday thanks to both of you

Comment: @Sam: Great. You want to mention about the file extension as well?

Comment: @Sam: Not necessary but good to specify an extension so that when you read your code say down the line in 6 months then you don't have to think hard on what the code is doing...

Comment: @SiddharthRout I added it. Thanks for the pointer (everyday I learn something new on this site) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error due to you missing a colon after the fileFormat parameter.

It should be `FileFormat:=xlExcel12`

---

Also you should append the file extension

```
"C:\Users\sxj2030\Documents\BC Validations\Fixed\" & _
 ActiveWorkbook.Name & "_" & Format(Date, "MMMddYYYY") & ".xlsb"
```

Comment: perfect thats what I was missing... thanks so much for your help... lesson learned no coding monday mornings

Comment: +1 :) @user2859648: If the file is saved then yes, `ActiveWorkbook.Name` will give you the extenstion as well. but since you are adding `& "_" & Format(Date, "MMMddYYYY")`, it will append to the name.

Comment: @Siddarth Rout:yea thats what found out when asnwer was edited with the .xlsb. I get the syntax now thank you